# How to check with a CAS if a surface is of general type?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, mathematical-software, software

The main question is:

> How to check with a CAS if a surface is of general type?

Magma's function `KodairaEnriquesType` is close to this,
but doesn't always work.

It has the optional parameter `CheckADE := true`.

Without it, it might return wrong result (got hurt by this).

With it, it might fail.

Special sufficient conditions will be appreciated too.

Appears to me possible approach is:  treat one variable
as parameter and if the genus is $0$ or $1$ it is not of general
type.

Comment: In theory I guess you can use Magma to compute a desingularization (eg. by successive blow-ups) and then use KodairaEnriquesType?

Comment: @J.C.Ottem Thank you. Maybe desingularization should be computed with something else, since Magma's builtin function have the same singularity limitation according to the documentation.